# Query a max cost value, based on max date, distinct to an inventory number

Tags: sql, oracle, querying

1. I need a query with a desired output shown in bullet #2.  Below is a simple query of the data. Notice avgcost can fluctuate for the same date.  I need the highest avgcost on the most recent date, distinct to the inventoryno.  Can someone help me write a script to do this?

Current query and output

```
select inventoryno, avgcost, dts
  from invtrans
 where DTS < '01-JAN-23'
 order by dts desc;
```

| INVENTORYNO | AVGCOST | DTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 264 | 52.36411 | 12/31/2022 |
| 264 | 52.36411 | 12/31/2022 |
| 264 | 52.36411 | 12/31/2022 |
| 507 | 149.83039 | 12/31/2022 |
| 6005 | 57.45968 | 12/31/2022 |
| 6005 | 57.45968 | 12/31/2022 |
| 6005 | 57.45968 | 12/31/2022 |
| 1518 | 4.05530 | 12/31/2022 |
| 1518 | 4.05530 | 12/31/2022 |
| 1518 | 4.05530 | 12/31/2022 |
| 1518 | 4.15254 | 12/31/2022 |
| 1518 | 4.15254 | 12/31/2022 |
| 1518 | 4.1525 | 12/31/2022 |
| 365 | 0.00000 | 2/31/2022 |
| 365 | 0.00000 | 2/31/2022 |
| 365 | 0.00000 | 2/31/2022 |

2. My proposed query which doesn't work error: 'not a single-group group function'

```
 Select distinct inventoryno, Max(avgcost), max(dts)
 from invtrans
 where DTS < '01-JAN-23'
 order by inventoryno;
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

| INVENTORYNO | AVGCOST | DTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 264 | 52.36411 | 12/31/2022 |
| 507 | 149.83039 | 12/31/2022 |
| 6005 | 57.45968 | 12/31/2022 |
| 1518 | 4.15254 | 12/31/2022 |
| 365 | 0.00000 | 2/31/2022 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `row_number` analytic function, *sort* rows per each `inventoryno` ordered by `dts` in descending order (so that the most recent rows are sorted first (note that your sample dates are either all the same, or invalid (there's no 31st of February so I modified it to 31st of December for `inventoryno` = 365)). Then extract rows that ranked as the highest.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     temp
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT inventoryno,
  5                avgcost,
  6                dts,
  7                ROW_NUMBER ()
  8                   OVER (PARTITION BY inventoryno
  9                         ORDER BY dts DESC, avgcost DESC) rn
 10           FROM invtrans)
 11  SELECT inventoryno, avgcost, dts
 12    FROM temp
 13   WHERE rn = 1;

INVENTORYNO    AVGCOST DTS
----------- ---------- ----------
        264   52,36411 12/31/2022
        365          0 12/31/2022
        507  149,83039 12/31/2022
       1518    4,15254 12/31/2022
       6005   57,45968 12/31/2022

SQL>
```